# Is there a way to make a map object repeat?

Tags: python

Say if I have a map object: `map(lambda x: int(x), "123")`, but I want 6 items, I would expect `1,2,3,1,2,3` (Note I don't want it in list format, I would use next to get each item), but instead I just get a StopIteration error once I pull out 3 items. I do have a workaround but it's not as clean as I would like:

```
def MakeMap(): return map(lambda x:int(x), "123")
mapped=MakeMap()
for i in range(6):
     try:
         print(next(mapped))
     except StopIteration:
         mapped=MakeMap()
         print(next(mapped))
```

While this works, as stated above I would like it to be just as easy as:

```
mapped=map(lambda x:int(x), "123")
for i in range(6):
    print(next(mapped))
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`itertools.cycle` is the general way to (indefinitely) repeat any iterator's sequence.

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> mapped = cycle(map(int, "123"))
>>> for i in range(6):
...    print(next(mapped))
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Do note the other change:  `lambda x: int(x)` works, but is an expensive and obscure way to spell plain old `int`.